# Phonegap Image Upload works only once

Tags: ajax, file-upload, cordova, file-transfer, photo-upload

my app needs to upload photos to a server. This works great when uploading the first captured photo. When I capture another photo, the upload fails.

Here is my code:

```
    // Upload files to server
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {

    $.mobile.loading( 'show' );
    var path = mediaFile;
    alert(path);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = new Object();
    params.fullpath = path;
    params.eventID = eventID;


    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = true;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload( path, "http://dev.tellthedj.de/db/uploadPhoto.php",
        function(result) {
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );
            alert("Foto erfolgreich hochgeladen");   

            // Geschossenes Foto aus Cache löschen
            var file = new FileEntry(); 
            file.fullPath = mediaFile;

            file.remove(success, fail);

            function success(){
                alert("success");
            }

            function fail(){
                alert("cache löschen nicht erfolgreich")
            }

        },
        function(error) {
            $.mobile.loading( 'hide' );
            alert("Upload nicht erfolgreich. Bitte checke deine Internet-Verbindung: ");
            console.log(error.message);
        },
        options
        );
}
```

mediaFile is the location of the captured photo in cache folder.
The second photo I want to upload always calls "Upload nicht erfolgreich..." and i got this error in LogCat

```
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783): {"target":"http:\/\/dev.tellthedj.de\/db\/uploadPhoto.php","source":"file:\/\/\/storage\/sdcard0\/Android\/data\/com.phonegap.getting.started\/cache\/1374735548710.jpg","http_status":0,"code":3}
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783): java.io.EOFException
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:314)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:301)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:130)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:630)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:385)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:534)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at org.apache.cordova.core.FileTransfer$3.run(FileTransfer.java:443)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-25 08:59:11.980: E/FileTransfer(6783): Failed after uploading 25260 of 25260 bytes.
```

The strange thing is, that the first upload works fine, the second fails with error code 3. The third works, the fourth -> error...

Comment: Refer answer to this question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723522/opening-camera-instance-from-a-web-app/17724235#17724235)

Comment: yeah I tried that so far! Thats the code from the PG documentation. Still the same issue. First upload win, second fails. The weird thing is, that the third, the fifth, the seventh... upload works, but not the second, fourth, sixth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just spent the last day or so working through the same issue. What worked for me was to set the header to close the connection.

options.headers = { "Connection":"close" };

Found this answer on the cordova Bug Tracker site:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2293?focusedCommentId=13696238&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13696238

Hope that helps, I know how frustrated I was with this one too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use xmlhttprequest level 2 via jquery.
its easy and configure your java file with chrome environment.
so your upload like web .

Comment: thx for your answer. but how do i get the file from the filepath to pass it via jQuery Ajax?

Comment: i edited my code. but know i don´t now how to store the HTMLimageobject to a folder on my Server

Comment: this is answer from another forum
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16224340/1234577
but I has try this jquery xhr level 2 when cretae project..
wait me for share my code in my blog..
I promise after i write in my blog i notif you :D

Comment: it´s weird because I tried it now with the exact same code from the Phonegap Documentation. But i still can upload only one picture, the second failed...

Comment: i´m still stuck on that problem. First upload works second responses with code 3. Third works, fourth reponses with 4...

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfixed bug in the phonegap library, since there were no bug fixes, i had to get it work by my work around (Basically reupload on every alternate failure):

```
ft.upload(path,
          encodeURI("http://yourdomain.com/upload.php"),
            function(result) {
                alert("Uploaded");
            },
            function(error) {
                ft.upload(path,
                encodeURI("http://yourdomain.com/upload.php"),
                function(result) {
                    alert("Uploaded");                  
                },
                function(error) {
                    alert("Error uploading image");
                },
                { fileName: name, fileKey: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg", chunkedMode: false }, true);     
            },
            { fileName: name, fileKey: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg", chunkedMode: false }, true);
```