# Phonegap camera.getPicture issues with upload

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cordova

I have two goals in my mobile application.

a) take picture with phone's camera and upload it to server
b) pick picture from phone's gallery and upload it to server

I have been using Phonegap and point "a" works well. Also "b".

Issue: it seems like every second upload fails. No matter if I start with point "a" or point "b". Or randomly combined.

Result:
1. success
2. failed
3. success
4. failed
4. etc.

Here is my code for point "a":

```
function getImageCamera() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhotoCamera, function(message) {
    },{
        targetWidth: 1200,
        targetHeight: 900, 
        quality: 75, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
    }
    );
}
```

and for point "b":

```
function getImageGallery() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhotoGallery, function(message) {
    },{
        targetWidth: 1200,
        targetHeight: 900, 
        quality: 75, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
    }
    );
}
```

Functions uploadPhotoCamera and uploadPhotoGallery are the same.

Here is Eclipse log:

```
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613): Error getting HTTP status code from connection.
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613): java.io.EOFException
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:484)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-14 22:44:15.303: W/FileTransfer(32613):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613): {"target":"http:\/\/some_IP\/api_upload.php","source":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/data\/com.tisamobile\/cache\/resize.jpg?1387057455160","http_status":0,"code":3}
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613): java.io.EOFException
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:573)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:821)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:495)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:484)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-14 22:44:15.311: E/FileTransfer(32613): Failed after uploading 103425 of 103425 bytes.
```

What could be wrong? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This one is resolved at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851259/phonegap-image-upload-works-only-once

Answered by rand_mem_RAM on Sep 7 at 5:07.

Answer (score 2):

**It's not a problem about getPicture functions.**

I've found the very simple solution.

In my opinion, the FileTransfer() of cordova plugin doesn't send the data about the end of file transfer to the server.

So, the server can't recognize the boundary of each file and, occurs the issue.

```
var url = "http://www.upload-server-domain";
var imgFileURI = '/filepath/test.jpg';
var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.upload('', encodeURI(url), null, null, null);   // SOLUTION : fake upload                
ft.upload(imgFileURI, encodeURI(url), fnSuccessCallback, fnErrorCallback, options); // real upload
```

I think the fake upload will be let a server know the file transfer is the end.

Because, the Content-Length is 0.

Comment: This could also work, I agree. My solution: when error occurs, I was calling ft.upload again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on phonegap 2.9.0 , after doing many failed trials to solve the problem, I did the following
- I created a new phonegap 3.5.0 project 
- I built the android platform from CLI 
- I copied the www folder to the new project root folder
- I added all needed plugins using CLI
- I did the necessary changes in top-level config.xml file for icon and splash screen because file construction is different
- I ran the project , and it is ok now.